# Не запускается страница в браузере 127.0.0.1 (не удается получить доступ к сайту)

Tags: python

Вот, что пишет Pycharm:

"" (venv) C:\Users\Python\PycharmProjects\untitled>python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Performing system checks...

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 05, 2019 - 16:36:14
Django version 2.2.4, using settings 'untitled.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Python\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Python\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
  File "C:\Users\Python\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 203, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
  File "C:\Users\Python\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd2 in position 0: invalid continuation byte""
```

Comment: Уважаемый автор, предоставьте, пожалуйста, код Вашей программы, чтобы участники сообщества могли разобраться в сути ошибки.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362957/builtins-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xd2-in-position-17?rq=1) англоязычный ответ на эту проблему. Ошибка в кодировке файла.